# Python class and main method error in python 2.6.6

Tags: python

I am newbie to python and I just started writing simple classes with main method.Please find below few lines of python code.I have just created main method with print statement

```
 def main():
        print("inside main method")
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

When I write above without class it is working properly without any errors but If I put the same code inside class I am facing NamedError in python.

```
class Test:
    def main():
        print("inside main method")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run above I am getting below error
NameError: name 'main' is not defined.

I am using Python 2.6.6 version

Comment: If you're a newbie, don't start with a long superseeded version of Python. If you want to learn Python2, use python 2.7.10 or so, and if you want to learn Python 3, use 3.4.2 or so.

Comment: When you put `main` inside a class, it is no longer accessible from the global scope like that.

Comment: Also, please make sure to format your code as code and your text not as code, to make your question legible

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as TigerhawkT3 stated, when you put main inside class, it is no longer accessible from the global scope. So if you want to make your main a part of class you should define it as the following:

```python
class Test:
    def main(self):
        print("inside main method")
```

And to be able to call it you should use the following:

```python
if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test().main()
```

I suggest you to read the following tutorial: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html